# Macbook won't connect to xfinity hotspot

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

Try as I might, I can't get my MacBook to talk to the local Xfinity hotspot, by which I mean the public hotspots called "xfinitywifi" (not my house's router).

My iPad connects to it fine and it gives me the magical sign-on page, which I do, and Bob's Your Uncle. But the MacBook -- nada -- just no network seen. I've tried with both Chrome and Safari.

What's supposed to happen (and which happens perfectly fine on the iPad) is that you go to some random url, and it redirects you first to an Xfinity specific login page, which you do, and then you're in. Again, my iPad does this exactly fine. But try as I might, I can't get my MacBook to do it on either Chrome or Safari, just sees no network at all.

I've tried turning off my firewalls, no joy. Some web surfing led me to a probably bogus theory about having to go to a non-https site.  I tried that too but it didn't work. I'm stumped.

BTW, my MacBook works fine on every other secondary hotspot I've tried, like the local library, so I know I can normally connect to public wifi.